# Difference between $K_{\alpha}$, $K_{\beta}$ and binding energies

Tags: energy, nuclear-physics, photons, x-rays

I'm having a small question regarding $K_{\alpha}$ and $K_{\beta}$ emissions.

If I'm not mistaken this happens when there is a transition from the L shell to the K shell (Depending on the orbital), in which a photon is emitted with a given energy.

My question is: Is there any difference between the energy of the photon that is emitted in  $K_{\alpha}$ emission for example, and the binding energy of the electron in the same orbital, or...?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It isn't clear what you're asking. The $K_{\alpha}$ energy is the difference in energy between the 1s and 2p atomic orbitals. The $K_{\beta}$ is the difference in energy between the 1s and 3p atomic orbitals.

Comment: I think it was just me who got a little confused.
I actually thought that the $K_{\alpha}$ was the same, as if the electron was removed from the atom while being in that orbital. But of course, that is not the case :/

So never mind the question. It was me being a little slow, sorry :)